# Отобразить надпись об успешной отправки формы без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, netcat

Всем добрый день! Есть html форма на NetCat. Как переделать форму и сделать скрипт на js, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Отправить страница не перезагружалась, и при успешной отправки формы внизу страницы выводилось сообщение Форма успешно отправлена. Пожалуйста помогите сделать, очень мало знаний по js и ajax.

Код самой формы:

```html
<div class="block-orderform">
  <div class="g-content">
    <div class="form js-pie">
      <form name="adminForm" id="" class="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/netcat/add.php">
        <div id="nc_moderate_form">
          <div class="nc_clear"></div>
          <input name="admin_mode" type="hidden" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="nc_token" value="584c57e113e76778b0700646510b9a97"><input name="catalogue" type="hidden" value="1">
          <input name="cc" type="hidden" value="21">
          <input name="sub" type="hidden" value="16"><input name="posting" type="hidden" value="1">
          <input name="curPos" type="hidden" value="0">
          <input name="f_Parent_Message_ID" type="hidden" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="f_Checked" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="atitle">Заказать аниматоров на праздник</div>
        <div class="wrap"><input class="js-pie input-text-1" type="text" name="f_Name" value="Ваше имя" onfocus="if(this.value=='Ваше имя'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Ваше имя'}"></div>
        <div class="wrap"><input class="js-pie input-text-1" type="text" name="f_Phone" value="Телефон" onfocus="if(this.value=='Телефон'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Телефон'}"></div>
        <div class="delim"></div>              
        <div class="wrap"><textarea class="js-pie" name="f_Descript" id="f_Descript" cols="30" rows="10" onfocus="if(this.value=='Комментарии'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Комментарии'}">Комментарии</textarea></div>
        <div class="wrap wrap_button"><button onclick="yaCounter12924709.reachGoal('ORDER-OK'); return true; al();"><span class="js-pie">Заказать</span></button></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Demon [чекни мой код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748919/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%83-gmail-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-custom-email) .

Answer (score 1):

Я использую 2 подхода:
**1. Более простой**:
- отправляйте форму ajax'ом на стандартный скрипт add.php указав GET-параметр `isNaked=1`, что получить "голый" контент (без стандартного шаблона страницы).
- укажите обработчику ответа, что ожидаете HTML-контент (т.к. неткат по-умолчанию отдаст вам "голый" чистый HTML-кусок разметки
- распарсите этот кусок как вам надо, например в настройках шаблона вывода инфоблока в поле "*Действие после добавления объекта*" добавьте какой-нибудь индикатов успешного добавления объекта, вроде `<span id='PlaceOrderSuccess'>Заказ успешно отправлен</span>`
Общий вид js функции (jQuery 3+)

```
$("#OrderForm").submit(function {
var form = $("#OrderForm");
$.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize() +"&isNaked=1", null, 'html')
    .done(function(response) {
        if($("#PlaceOrderSuccess", response).length!=-1){
            alert('Заказ успешно отправлен');
        }
        else alert('Произошла ошибка\n\r'+$(".warnText", response));
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
        alert('Произошла ошибка при отправке формы');
    }
    return false;
});
```

**2. Второй способ более сложный** 
и заключается в частичной доработке исходного скрипта add.php, но позволяет получать ответ в JSON-формате. В том же каталоге /netcat/add.php можете создать дубликат файла, например ajax_add.php и исправить в нем некоторые строки ближе к концу файла:

```
if ($File_Mode) {
    require_once $INCLUDE_FOLDER . 'index_fs.inc.php';
    if (!$templatePreview) {
        $nc_result_msg = preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/", "", nc_result_msg);
        $nc_result_msg = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", " ", $nc_result_msg);
        $data['content'] = $nc_result_msg;
        if ($warnText) {
            $data['warnText'] = $warnText;
        }
        echo nc_array_json($data);
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else { ...
```

Все в тех же настройках шаблона вывода инфоблока в поле "Действие после добавления объекта" укажите какую-нибудь индикацию статуса успешной отправки формы, вроде:

```
$data['Status'] = 1; // заказ сохранен успешно
echo json_encode($data); //отдать ответ в JSON-формате
```

В отличии от первого способа, в js здесь отправляйте данные на новый скрипт и укажите, что ждете JSON-объект

```
$.post("/netcat/ajax-add.php", form.serialize() +"&isNaked=1", null, 'html')
```

Далее без лишних проблем обращайтесь сразу к нужным переменным в ответе:

```
if(response.status==1){
    alert('Заказ успешно отправлен');
}
```