# Отправлять почту с сервера на почту Gmail (у меня custom email)

Tags: php, email, smtp

Проблема состоит в том, что когда я с сайта принимаю на свою запасную почту (на ...@gmail.com) форму обратной связи, то все работает нормально, почта приходит. Когда дело доходит до  того, что я должен отправить с сайта на почту сайта (пример. @yourdomain.com), то почта не приходит. Как это исправить?

вот мой код отправки на сервер:

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FeedBack</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#feedback").submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "feedback_lib.php",
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $("#load").fadeIn(400);
                        },
                        type: "post",
                        data: $("#feedback").serialize(),
                        success: function(answer) {
                            $("#answer").html(answer);
                        }
                    }).done(function() {
                        $("#load").fadeOut(400);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="feedback" action="" name="feedback" method="post">
            <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" />
            <br />
            <input id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="surname" />
            <br />
            <input id="enquiry" name="enquiry" placeholder="enquiry" />
            <br />
            <input id="organisation" name="organisation" placeholder="organisation" />
            <br />
            <input id="email" name="email_form" placeholder="email_form" />
            <br />
            <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="7" cols="40" placeholder="сообщение"></textarea>
            <br />
            <button name="send">отправить</button>
        </form>
        <img id="load" src="load.gif" style="display: none;" />
        <div id="answer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $surname = $_POST["surname"];
    $email = $_POST["email_form"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $result = 0;

    if ((strlen($email) < 5) or (strlen($message) < 10)) $result = 1; // длинна сообщения
    else {
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $subject = "Письмо с Вашего сайта http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/";
            $header = "From <".$email.">\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
            $text = "message from ".$email."\n name: ".$name."\n surname: ".$surname."\n message: ".$message;
            mail("you@example.com", $subject, $text, $header);
            $result = 3; //письмо отправлено
        }
        else $result = 2; // неправильный email
    }
    echo getAnswer($result);

    function getAnswer($result = 0) {
        switch ($result) {
            case 0: $answer = "";
            break;
            case 1: $answer = "<p style='color: red;'>Минимальная длинна собщения 10 символов, а email - 5!</p>";
            break;
            case 2: $answer = "<p style='color: red;'>Неправильный email! Проверьте.</p>";
            break;
            case 3: $answer = "<p style='color: green;'>Письмо отправлено.</p>";
        }
        return $answer;
    }
```

**GIF:**

[Load.gif](http://gph.is/2jjvoJq)

.

.

Как должно выглядить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выглядит на самом деле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер не мой - провайдера.

P.S. Когда почта не перенаправлялась на Google - все работало нормально)

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно создать не перенаправление, а дублирование письма. Проблема может быть в том, что когда почта уходит на `gmail` - это единственный экземпляр письма, который отправляется с сервера, и больше никуда оно не пойдет.

Comment: @Klimenkomud хмм... я вот что получаю... я пока не знаю как правильно тебе ответить на комментарий. Опираясь на информацию, данную в ответе, я настраиваю сейчас DKIM. Это займет 1-2 дня. Кстати, вот как приходит мне email - http://oi63.tinypic.com/dza06s.jpg

Answer (score 1):

По имеющимся данным нельзя однозначно сказать в чем может быть дело. Посмотрите для начала почтовый лог и убедитесь, что почта вообще отправляется и поступает на ящик *@yourdomain.com.

Также непонятно куда именно в конечном итоге приходит почта с вашего ящика *@yourdomain.com. Это пересылка на Gmail? Если так, то вполне возможно, что сервер Gmail отказывается принимать письма с неверно настроенного почтового домена (DKIM, SPRF, DMARC и т.д.).

Comment: сейчас добавлю уточнение

Comment: Уточнения добавлены

Comment: DKIM не настроен. сейчас настраиваю. позже пройдусь по следующим сокращениям. Спасибо за направление к исправлению ошибки

Comment: @AntonRogalskiy очень рекомендую для начала настроить DKIM и SPRF. не знаю как обстоят дела сейчас, но ранее Gmail вообще отказывался принимать почту с новых доменов, у которых не настроены эти записи (то есть, они идут не как carantin, а вообще rejected, т.е. не попадают ни во входящие, ни в спам).