# Письма в спаме. Нужно ли менять G Suite?

Tags: email, gmail, спам

Есть несколько доменов, подключенных к G Suite, потому при рассылке писем в поле "отправитель" указывается тот IP, который выдаст Google. Схема та же, что при использовании обычной почты Gmail.

Проблема в том, что письма с некоторых доменов попадают в спам, потому что отправляются с IP, который находится в blacklist'e у нескольких популярных сервисов. Т.е. есть диапазон гугловских IP, с которых отсылаются письма, и некоторые из этих IP - в блэклисте.

DKIM / DMARC/ SPF настроено, всё ок. Настроено правильно. Проверка проходит. В различных онлайн сервисах определения spam score всё ок, кроме того, что IP отправителя находится в ±4 блэклистах.

**Как решить данную проблему ?**

- Изменить выбор с G Suite в пользу другого email хостинг-провайдера? Тогда не факт, что и некоторые из его IP's не находятся в блэклистах.
- Свой почтовый сервер?
- Иные варианты?

**Google говорит**, что знает о проблеме, но блеклист-сервисы им не отвечают либо не хотят разблокировать эти IP. Их решение: подождать.
Конечно же, такое решение мне не подходит.

Comment: У меня тоже идет борьба с отправками писем....  [моя борьба с GSuite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748919/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%83-gmail-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-custom-email)

Comment: @Antonio112009, какие результаты?

Comment: печальные. У меня проблема с отправкой формы с сервера себе на почту в GSuite. Когда отправляешь на почту НЕ того же домена, что и вебсайт - все работает, но письма приходят в спам и в отправителях показывается не info@yourdomain.com , а мой логин и "сервак" login@cpanel.com. пытаюсь понять как серверу выделить info@yourdomain.com email

Comment: та же самая проблема. сапорт гугла говорит что проблем не видит и все настроено правильно. Сказали что видимо так настроены ящики получателей gmail) Конечно же это бред.